# How do I convert a CString to a BYTE?

Tags: c++, string, mfc, type-conversion, byte

I have CStrings in my program that contain BYTE information like the following:

```
L"0x45"
```

I want to turn this into a BYTE type with value `0x45`.  How do I do this?  All examples I can find are trying to get the literal byte value of the string itself, but I want to take the value contained within the CString and convert THAT to a BYTE.  How do I achieve this?

Comment: `std::stoi` and related functions exist for a reason. Even the old way of stringstreams still supports hex.

Comment: I've tried stoi and _wtoi and they both just returned 0 instead of 0x45.

Comment: Take a closer look at the function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`wcstoul()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9xb7x1.aspx) conversion function, specifying base 16.

e.g.:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <stdlib.h> // for wcstoul()
#include <iostream> // for console output
#include <atlstr.h> // for CString

int main() 
{
    CString str = L"0x45";

    static const int kBase = 16;    // Convert using base 16 (hex)
    unsigned long ul = wcstoul(str, nullptr, kBase);
    BYTE b = static_cast<BYTE>(ul);

    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned long>(b) << std::endl;
}
```

> ```
> C:\Temp>cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo test.cpp
> ```

Output:

> ```
> 69
> ```

---

As an alternative, you can also consider using new C++11's [**`std::stoi()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404860.aspx):

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <iostream> // for console output
#include <string>   // for std::stoi()
#include <atlstr.h> // for CString

int main() 
{
    CString str = L"0x45";

    static const int kBase = 16;    // Convert using base 16 (hex)
    int n = std::stoi(str.GetString(), nullptr, kBase);
    BYTE b = static_cast<BYTE>(n);

    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned long>(b) << std::endl;
}
```

**NOTE**
In this case, since `std::stoi()` expects a `const std::wstring&` argument, you must *explicitly* get the `const wchar_t*` pointer for the `CString` instance, either using `CString::GetString()` as I did (and I prefer), or using `static_cast<const wchar_t*>(str)`.
Then, a temporary `std::wstring` will be built to be passed to `std::stoi()` for the conversion.